# Roles of Second Derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

How a second derivative at any point gives a curve that touches the real curve(being differentiated) at that particular point?

Answer (score 2):

You need not merely the second derivative of $f$ at $c$ but the second-order Taylor polynomial $f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)+\frac12 f''(c)(x-c)^2$. That parabola will touch the graph of $f$ at the point $(c,f(c))$.